# setMeta не устанавливает новые значения?

Tags: php

Добрый день есть такие файлы

```
default.php
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <?=$this->getMeta()?>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Шаблон Default</h1>

<?=$content; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Где с помощью getMeta выводится мета теги. Они и выводится но значения что я записываю в MainController не идут

```
namespace app\controllers;


class MainController extends AppController
{

  public function indexAction(){

   $dsa = $this->setMeta('Главная страница','Мой суперский сайт', 'keyowrds');

  }

}
```

controller.php

```php
<?php


namespace ishop\base;


abstract class Controller
{

  public $route;
  public $controller;
  public $model;
  public $view;
  public $layout;
  public $prefix;
  public $data = [];
  public $meta = ['title' => '', 'description'=>'', 'keywords'=>''];

  public function __construct($route)
  {
    $this->route = $route;
    $this->controller = $route['controller'];
    $this->model = $route['controller'];
    $this->view = $route['action'];
    $this->prefix = $route['prefix'];

  }

  public function getView(){
    $viewObject = new View($this->route, $this->layout, $this->view, $this->meta);
    $viewObject->render($this->data);
  }

  public function set($data){
    $this->data = $data;
  }

  public function setMeta($title = '', $description = '', $keywords = ''){
    $this->$meta['title'] = $title;
    $this->$meta['description'] = $description;
    $this->$meta['keywords'] = $keywords;
  }



}
```

view.php

```php
<?php


namespace ishop\base;


use ishop\App;
use mysql_xdevapi\Exception;

class View
{

  public $route;
  public $controller;
  public $model;
  public $view;
  public $layout;
  public $prefix;
  public $data = [];
  public $meta = [];

  public function __construct($route,  $layout = '', $view = '', $meta)
  {
    $this->route = $route;
    $this->controller = $route['controller'];
    $this->model = $route['controller'];
    $this->view = $view;
    $this->prefix = $route['prefix'];
    $this->meta = $meta;
    if($layout === false){
      $this->layout = false;
    }
    else{
      $this->layout = $layout ?: LAYOUT;
    }

  }


  public function render($data){

    $viewfile = APP ."/views/{$this->prefix}{$this->controller}/{$this->view}.php";

    if(is_file($viewfile)){
      ob_start();
      require_once $viewfile;
      $content = ob_get_clean();

    }
    else{
      throw new \Exception("Не найден вид  {$viewfile}",500);
    }

    if(false !== $this->layout){
      $layoutFile = APP . "/views/layouts/{$this->layout}.php";
      if(is_file($layoutFile)){
        require_once $layoutFile;
      }
      else{
        throw new \Exception("Шаблон {$this->layout} не найден",500);
      }
    }

  }

  public function getMeta(){
    $output = "<title>" . $this->meta['title'] .  "</title>" .PHP_EOL;
    $output .= '<meta name="description" content="' . $this->$meta['description'] . '">' .PHP_EOL;
    $output .= '<meta name="keywords" content="' . $this->$meta['keywords'] . '">' .PHP_EOL;
    return $output;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы обращаетесь к свойству объекта анонимно через `$this->$meta`, когда оно у вас определено `public $meta`, замените ваш метод на этот:

```
public function setMeta($title = '', $description = '', $keywords = ''){
    $this->meta['title'] = $title;
    $this->meta['description'] = $description;
    $this->meta['keywords'] = $keywords;
}
```

Вы обращались `$this->$meta`, переменной `$meta` в методе `setMeta()` не было объявлено и судя по всему в глобальной видимости тоже - и вообще так делать вам не нужно было(специально ее где-то определять). Напомню, что данное обращение `$this->$meta` является анонимным, или "magic access", потому что вы не знаете что лежит в переменной `$meta`, там может лежать значение `'trump'` и получается что вызываете `$this->trump`.

---

Вам не имеет смысла определять переменную `dsa`, потому что метод `setMeta()` ничего не возвращает(`void`). Можете просто ее убрать:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->setMeta('Главная страница','Мой суперский сайт', 'keyowrds');
}
```

`<?=$content; ?>` - `;` необязательно ставить, в таких случаях она мозолит глаза и ухудшает читаемость.